# Elegant pair wise scalar product of many vectors in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 sets of `n*m` vectors `x_ij` and `y_ij` of dimension `d` stored in two `np.ndarray` `X` and `Y` of shape `n*m*d`.
I want to get the `n*m` matrix of scalar products `x_ij.y_ij`.
At the moment I do this like that:

```
(X.T.reshape((d,m*n)) * Y.T.reshape((d,n*m))).sum(axis=0).reshape((m,n)).T
```

It works but feels uglier / hackier than it needs to be. Is there a more elegant way to do this operation?

Comment: Shouldn't you have posted this question on CodeReview?  :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334719/simplifying-looped-numpy-operations

Comment: @hpaulj yes,... my comment was before he clarified his needs :)

Comment: Pot ... kettle ...

Comment: @luckytaxi it's hard to argue that the best way between my solution and the answer below is just a matter of opinion...  but whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are keeping the first two axes aligned and sum-reducing the last axes on both inputs. For such a case, one efficient way to solve it would be with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), like so -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',X,Y)
```