# Simplifying looped numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to learn to efficiently implement various neural nets in python and am currently trying to implement this model

[image].

However, I am having trouble using numpy operations to implement the summation.

I have been following [this existing implementation](https://github.com/shashankg7/multimodal-neural-language-models/blob/master/mnlm_code/lm/lbl.py#L119L140) and am trying to simplify it, but it's not entirely clear to me what all of the array operations being performed are achieving. My interpretation is that the C's are multiplied through each of the columns of R and summed. However, my einsum implementation `np.einsum('ijk,km->ij', C, R)` doesn't seem to produce the required result.

I would appreciate some pointers towards simplifying this implementation. My current attempts have been to use `np.einsum` but that hasn't gotten me anywhere so far.

Code to simplify (explained in image/first link):

```
batchsize = X.shape[0]
R = self.R
C = self.C
bw = self.bw

# Obtain word features
tmp = R.as_numpy_array()[:,X.flatten()].flatten(order='F')
tmp = tmp.reshape((batchsize, self.K * self.context))
words = np.zeros((batchsize, self.K, self.context))
for i in range(batchsize):
    words[i,:,:] = tmp[i,:].reshape((self.K, self.context), order='F')
words = gpu.garray(words)

# Compute the hidden layer (predicted next word representation)
acts = gpu.zeros((batchsize, self.K))
for i in range(self.context):
    acts = acts + gpu.dot(words[:,:,i], C[i,:,:])
```

Comment: This is better suited for [code-review] unless you have a specific question/error.

Comment: @JulienBernu Sorry, I am new here. I have edited.

Comment: You also need to explain what "required result" is. People are unlikely to dig through an entire paper to understand what you want. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JulienBernu Done. Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Stay on SO.  There's a lot more `numpy` expertise here than on CR.  CR is better for code style details.  Replacing loops with numpy operations is a frequent SO topic.  That said, you'll get a better response if you provide the MCVe.  We like to copy-n-paste code, play with it, and copy it back in an answer.

Comment: At a minimum, tell us the dimensions and shape of all arrays.  I also notice the use of `gpu`.  I'm not familiar with that.  That looks `np` like, but does it have functions like `einsum`?

Answer (score 2):

Creating a small `words`:

```
In [565]: words = np.zeros((2,3,4))
In [566]: tmp = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape((2,3*4))
In [567]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     words[i,:,:] = tmp[i,:].reshape((3,4),order='F')
     ...:     
In [568]: tmp
Out[568]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
In [569]: words
Out[569]: 
array([[[  0.,   3.,   6.,   9.],
        [  1.,   4.,   7.,  10.],
        [  2.,   5.,   8.,  11.]],

       [[ 12.,  15.,  18.,  21.],
        [ 13.,  16.,  19.,  22.],
        [ 14.,  17.,  20.,  23.]]])
```

I'm pretty sure this can be done without the loop

```
In [577]: C = np.ones((4,3,3))
In [578]: acts = np.zeros((2,3))
In [579]: for i in range(4):
     ...:     acts += np.dot(words[:,:,i], C[i,:,:])
     ...:     
In [580]: acts
Out[580]: 
array([[  66.,   66.,   66.],
       [ 210.,  210.,  210.]])
```

This `dot` loop can be expressed in `einsum` as:

```
In [581]: np.einsum('ijk,kjm->im', words, C)
Out[581]: 
array([[  66.,   66.,   66.],
       [ 210.,  210.,  210.]])
```

This is summing on `j` and `k`.  In the loop version the sum on `j` was done in the `dot`,and the sum on `k` was done in the loop.  But for very large arrays, and with `gpu` speedup, the loop version might be faster.  If the problem space gets too big, `einsum` can be slow and even hit memory errors (though the newest version has some optimization options).

`words` can be created from `tmp` without a loop:

```
In [585]: tmp.reshape(2,3,4, order='F')
Out[585]: 
array([[[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
        [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
        [ 2,  5,  8, 11]],

       [[12, 15, 18, 21],
        [13, 16, 19, 22],
        [14, 17, 20, 23]]])
```